# Reboot a router using PHP and curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to write a PHP script to reboot my tp-link router that has the IP address of http://192.168.1.1

Using  PHP, I have tried the following script and it still fails to work:

```html
 <?php
$ch = curl_init();
$cookie="./cookie.txt" ;
$data = array('Username' => 'admin', 'Password' => 'admin');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 

$o=curl_exec($ch);
echo $o;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: So what does `$o` output?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: sir i add that its not basic authentification its normal autentification like any forum login or member login

the output is

The requested URL /_Incapsula_Resource was not found on this server.


HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: text/html Cache-Control: no-cache Connection: close Content-Length: 625 X-Iinfo: 3-3507102-0 0NNN RT(1471535525040 0) q(-1 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1) b1 


HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: text/html Cache-Control: no-cache Connection: close Content-Length: 625 X-Iinfo: 3-3507102-0 0NNN RT(1471535525040 0) q(-1 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1) b1

Comment: any help  please !